# how to skip 'Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...' on the first run of the app?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to run an app and it fails after `Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...`. It tries to download some files in cache. The files have `.pom` extension. On my pc I don't have access to the resources that it tries to load the files from. But I do have the access on my phone. I can download these files through my phone and then send them to the pc. I can't use proxy.

**The question is**: Where does gradle store these cache files and is it possible to specify path to those files from the disk so it will load these files instead of using the url paths?

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             67.2s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Retrying Gradle Build: #1, wait time: 100ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-b20183e04096094bcc37d9cde2a4b96f5cc684cf.pom'.
               > Connect to storage.googleapis.com:443 [storage.googleapis.com/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
```